# How to get discord bot guilds with axios

Tags: javascript, axios, discord.js

OK so i want to use axios to get the total guilds where the bot is in using the discord api by fetching it through axios or node-fetch! I dont want to use discord.js here because of some reasons. I just need the discord api endpoint and the way to get all the discord bot guilds!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know and from my research in the [Discord API docs](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild), it looks like there's no endpoint to get all the guilds your bot is at. It makes sense: some are in millions of servers. Discord.js, with its [`GuildManager`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildManager) in [`<client>.guilds`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=guilds), creates a list of all the guilds it receives events from. In theory, a guild where absolutely nothing happens would not be listed, since it's based on the cache.

So, no endpoint for that. You may still create a script that does the job and caches the guilds, but that would be kind of silly since discord.js does all the hard work for you.

#### Update

I tried this before you did.
This is what `GET https://discord.com/api/guilds` returns:

```json
{
    "message": "405: Method Not Allowed",
    "code": 0
}
```

While `GET https://discord.com/api/guilds/GUILD_ID/channels` returns an array of channels. This seems to prove what I thought: guilds are not given by the API for performance reasons.